# Joomla Dynamic Contents in Article

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-template

I am new to Joomla, I am currently trying to set up a information portal for a university which will have information regarding all the faculty members. The information to be displayed would have information like Subjects they teach, total experience, phone number, email id, address, etc etc.

Normal way to deal with this to write a new article about each faculty member.
But I want this to be more dynamic. I dont like the idea to create a new article for each faculty. I am looking for a way that all the information(subjects, email, phone, etc) should be stored in database and while displaying all information should be fetched from the database itself and should be displayed in a preformated way.

Please let me know if anyone is having any idea regarding this..Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a CCK plugin like [K2](http://getk2.org/) and add and Extra Field Group, [like this](http://www.joomtraining.com.au/tutorials/k2/using-extra-fields) ...  that way it could be added in the admin. Done what you're doing with many types of content this way.

### UPDATE: Just remembered [this great little component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/joodatabase) called joodatabase

Comment: Sadly, your 3rd link is now broken.  What's the name of **this great little component** so the new link can be searched for?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a module, or use one from the Joomla extension directory (You're looking for a directory module). A module in Joomla will allow you to access the data stored in the database.

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=directory

Answer (score 1):

You can include an external PHP Script in your article and let the php script handle the data based on the query string paramerter(may be like faculty id or something). In order to do that you will need to install a module. `http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/60`. Using this module you should be able to include a php script within the article.

Comment: would this be SEO friendly..I mean the final content would be visible as HTML ?

Comment: yes, it will work same as an article. Also one more thing, if there is a static content you want to add above or below the output of your php script, you can add it (after/before) your call to the script in the article.

Comment: but it seems this plugin is not compatible with joomla 2.5 .. what do you think ?

Comment: I have not worked on Joomla for a year or so. Not sure how much they have changed the structure for plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but still a hot topic 
I think Dynamic Articles with TinyButStrong would solve this problem 
https://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/joomla/tinybutstrong_help.html

For example adding Tag or Search Parameter into content if no article exist.
Place for much more phantasy